Generating PowerBI report URLs that include query strings automatically (instead of manually)
All of the documentation and examples I've seen thus far cover how to manually create a URL that includes filters using a query string.  It seems programmatically trivial to generate a URL for the report author that includes a pre-formed query string (the filtering criteria, escaped characters, etc) so I can't help feel that I'm missing something embarrassingly obvious -- like a button or option somewhere to select some filters and spit out a pre-baked URL (report URL, the query string, escaped characters, etc).
Is using DAX the best way to generate a URL with a query string, is there some website I haven't discovered yet that can generate the query string for you based on the filtering criteria you type in, or does can Power BI already do this?  Or is manually generating the URL the way to go in 2024?
